# Android - View.GONE bug in 5.1

Tags: android

There is an coach marks view overlay that I am showing during the first time start up of my app. After a user sees the overlay and performs an action I am setting the view's visibility to View.GONE. This has worked for 4.0.4 - 5.0.2 versions of Android. However I am seeing crashes in our logs for several 5.1 users. The crashes seem to be saying that the view that is being set to GONE is being eventually nulled out and when I call getVisibility() on the view I get a null pointer exception. I am not setting the view to null but it seems like Android is deciding that the view should be null since it's visibility is set to GONE. This doesn't happen every time a user uses a 5.1 device but seems to be happening when a user leaves the app for a while and comes back to it. The error only occurs on 5.1, all other Android versions work fine.

Is this an Android 5.1 bug or do I need to handle the view's visibility differently?

Edit: Here is the stack trace. Obviously the view is null and that is why I am getting the NullPointerException. However, I am not doing anything to make the view null. I believe Android 5.1 is eventually deciding that the view should be null since its visibility is set to gone, so it randomly sets the view to null. This doesn't happen in any other versions of Android, even in Android 5.0.2 the code works perfectly fine.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RelativeLayout.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
at com.peaksware.trainingpeaks.activities.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu (MainActivity.java:493)
```

Comment: No code? No stack trace? It will be difficult to help you. Bear in mind that "when a user leaves the app for a while and comes back to it", your process may have been terminated, so make sure that you are properly re-initializing your activity/fragment/whatever.

Comment: getVisibility() returns an int which is a primitive type and cannot be null. Therefore, if you're getting a NullPointerException when calling it, then your view is null not the visibility.

Comment: Please post the relevant section of code

Comment: Post your code from the onCreateOptionsMenu function of the MainActivity class.